# How to take first five values on a note document and put into a list (Python)

Tags: python

I have a note document (.txt) that has numeric values. There is one number per line and there is about 20 lines. How can I grab the first 5 numbers from the file and put it into a list in Python? Simple question but I can't seem to find out how to do it. Also, is there a way to check how many lines are present in the file and receive a value for the length of the file (no of rows).

Comment: `fiveNums = [int(x.strip()) for x in open('my_document.txt').readlines()[5:]]`

Comment: Will this work for values such as 123.234 (not int)

Comment: No, then use `float` ...

Comment: For some reason that gets the last five numbers, not the first 5

Comment: I got it no worries

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of this should work

```
pd.read_csv("sample.txt", nrows=5).values.tolist()
```

Comment: This gives the last 5 numbers, not the first 5

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

numbers = re.findall(r"\-?\d+\.?\d*", content)[:5]
numbers = [float(x) for x in numbers]
print(numbers)

number_of_lines = len(content.split("\n"))
print(number_of_lines)
```

Input:

```
abc 1) def, abc
2, ghi
jkl +3
mno 5.555 pq.r
tuv -15.0
0.0 wxyz
the end
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.555, -15.0]
7
```